# Assigning different classes on different screen sizes with css

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, less

Let I have 2 classes named `class1` and `class2`. Also I have an element with `id="responsive_element"`. What I want is to assign `class1` to this element when screen size is below 768px and `class2` otherwise.

I can do this in Less like:

```
@media screen and (max-width:768px){
  #responsive_element{
    .class1()
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width:769px){
  #responsive_element{
    .class2()
  }
}
```

Is there any "CSS only" way to achieve this?

Edit: I think I couldn't explain my question clear enough. I am already able to do this by compiling less, but the size of css file grows for the long class definitions and using them too much. I want to handle it with simply changing class of the element .

Comment: I guess you're approaching this issue the wrong way. You don't assign classes based on screen size. You assign classes and then define what each class does based on screen size.

Comment: @JordiNebot No, I have two classes already defined and used by some other elements and also have nothing to do with the screen size. Like `.class1{color:red;} .class2{color:blue;}`. But I want my element to use one of them on big screens and other in smaller ones. I want to do it without writing the same things again and again.

Comment: Note that the intended method for using Less in production is to convert Less stylesheets into CSS.  So, when you say you want to do this "without writing the same things again and again", that's what Less is *for*.  You write it in Less so that you, as the programmer, need not write the same things again and again even though in the final, production CSS, they must be written again and again because of inherent CSS limitations.

Comment: Why don't you add all the classes in HTML all together to your `ID` and define the respective CSS inside respective `media-query breakpoint`? in this way,

Answer (score 0):

Except for the `.class1()` and `.class2()` calls, your Less code already is CSS.  Specifically, the `@media` queries that apply styling based on screen size aren't Less-specific.  So, for example, the following is pure CSS:

```
@media screen and (max-width:768px){
  #responsive_element{
    color: blue;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width:769px){
  #responsive_element{
    color: red;
  }
}
```

If you want to convert your Less into CSS, all you need to do is copy the CSS code from `.class1` and `.class2` into the place of the `.class1()` and `.class2()` calls.  In fact, since Less is implemented as a converter to CSS, you can just use the online converter at [LESS2CSS](http://less2css.org) to do the conversion for you.

If you're asking if there's a way in plain CSS to write these queries so that they use an existing `.class1` and `.class2` style definition without copying, then I believe the answer is no.  The main reason Less was invented was because CSS doesn't support this kind of reuse of styling information.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean, is there a way to use CSS alone to change the class of an element in response to changing screen sizes (literally, adding or removing new classnames to the element's HTML "class" attribute so CSS for different classes will take effect on that element), then the answer is simply "no, you cannot do this with CSS alone".

(Less can't do this either.  Your original Less code doesn't change the class attribute of the element, as you can plainly see by looking at the generated CSS.  It just uses classes as a handy trick to name sections of shareable CSS.)

The only way to change the element's class in the manner you seem to want is to make changes to the DOM, which you can obviously do via JavaScript but not with CSS alone.